# Google calendar v3 API - how to emulate batch requests?

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

[Official documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/getting_started.html) does not mention batch requests for newest protocol version.

How to emulate this future?

Is it possible use [HTTP Pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) with overloaded protocol method X-HTTP-METHOD
or is it better use twisted and running multiple requests at the same time or library like asyncore?

Without any means how to run batch requests google calendar data protocol v3 seems to me unusable for any synchronization.

Comment: Why does the lack of batching make it unusable for synchronization? I'm using it for that just fine in an application with 30,000 users.

Comment: We have implemented sync through the CalDAV API into our web based application and sometimes when we wanted to push around thousand events to GCal it took few minutes and consistently ended with 403 error. Also network roundtrip makes pushing individual events quite time ineffective. Can you explain how you push events to gcal in your application (is your application also web based?) ?